# Cannot instantiate abstract class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model - Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to extract the building of an Eloquent query as I want to reuse this code with many different models. In the controller, I have:

```
$inputs = Input::all();
$user =  new Eloquent;
$result = Helpers::buildQuery($user, $inputs);
```

And the Helpers class:

```
<?php namespace ArgumentClub;

class Helpers {

    public static function buildQuery(Eloquent $model, $inputs)
    {
        $limit = isset($inputs['limit']) ? $inputs['limit'] : 10;
        $offset = isset($inputs['offset']) ? $inputs['offset'] : 0;
        list($orderCol, $orderBy) = isset($inputs['order']) ? explode(",", $inputs['order']) : explode(",", 'created_at,DESC');

        $result = $model
            ->orderBy($orderCol, $orderBy)
            ->skip($offset)
            ->take($limit)
            ->get();

        return $result;
    }
}
```

So, how can I pass in the model and have it query that model, returning the Eloquent collection?

Comment: `Eloquent` is an abstract class. You need to instantiate your actual model class. `$user = new User;`

Comment: The problem is that I need the buildQuery method to expect an Eloquent model, but not a specific one. Not sure how to do this.

Comment: You don't have to change the `buildQuery` method. Just instantiate `new User` and pass that. The type restriction will still work because your model extends `Eloquent`

Comment: Thanks, if you write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`Eloquent` (which is an alias for `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`) is an abstract class. You can't instantiate it. Instead you have to do this:

```
$inputs = Input::all();
$user =  new User;
$result = Helpers::buildQuery($user, $inputs);
```

The type restriction `buildQuery(Eloquent $model, $inputs)` will still work fine because `User` extends `Eloquent` and therefore is accepted by the method.

---

A little sidenote, you might also want to think about creating a base model to extend `Eloquent` and share functionality between all models.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass your model class for exemple a `User` model which extend eloquent:

```
$inputs = Input::all();
$user =  new User;
$result = Helpers::buildQuery($user, $inputs);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `ungaurd()` and `regaud()` before and after your seeder classes in `run()` method of `DatabaseSeeder.php`

```
 \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::unguard();

 //$this->call(UsersTableSeeder::class);

 \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::reguard();
```

This solved my problem.